# Calendar Month and Year Not changing on dropdown year and month

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar, semantic-ui

I am using rzymek:fullcalendar package.
I just create a select list using semantic ui dropdown

```
<div class="ui compact selection dropdown">
      <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
      <div class="text">Compact</div>
      <div class="menu">
          <div class="item">January 2015</div>
      </div>
</div>
```

---

Create A calendar (call the fullcalendar template):-

```
<div class="calendar">
    {{>fullcalendar options id="myCalendar"}}
</div>
```

---

Changing the calendar month and year like this:-

```
$('.ui.selection.dropdown')
    .dropdown('restore default text')
        .dropdown({
            onChange: function (val) {
                var monthAndYear = val.split(" ");
                console.log(monthAndYear[0]);
                var today = new Date();
                 Session.set('date'monthAndYear[1]+'-0'+MonthList.indexOf(monthAndYear[0]));
                $('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({
                    gotoDate: moment(Session.get('date')),
                });
            }
        });
```

---

But it's not working. I don't know why ?

Comment: You're trying to select something with an id of `calendar`: `$('#calendar')` There is no element with an id of `calendar` in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but it's also not working.

Comment: Thanks for replay but nothing come up in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your template with **class** `calendar` has been added to the HTML you can use `$('#myCalendar')`.

If the calendar is already rendered you can't use:

```
$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar({gotoDate: moment(Session.get('date'))});
```

To go to a date you might want to call:

```
$('#myCalendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', moment(Session.get('date')));
```